# No suitable media source factory found for content type: 2 (type 2 is M3U8)

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, m3u8, exoplayer-media-item

I'm getting this error when using exoplayer even though i'm specifying the mimo type so don't understand why this crash is happening. The version i'm using is 2.18.7:

```
   videoUrl?.let {
                if (it.endsWith(".m3u8")) {
                    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(it)
                        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                        .build()
                    exoPlayer?.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                } else {
                    exoPlayer?.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(it))
                }
            }
```

I was expecting for the video to play normally

Answer (score 2):

To [play HLS streams](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/hls) (or DASH, Smooth Streaming), you need to add the HLS dependency to your `build.gradle` file.

For Media3 ExoPlayer, that is:

```
androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls
```

So, add:

```
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.1.1"
```

(Replace the version number with the most recent one.)

And for ExoPlayer 2.x, it is:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls
```

Comment: I added the dependency and I still get this error, my code is almost identical to what you posted.  Is there something else you had to do in addition to the dependency?

Comment: Hum i actually only added the HLS

Comment: there is no need to specify the mimeType

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I updated your answer a bit to provide more context.